# PyPy doesn't find a module made of only *.pyc files

Tags: python, python-2.7, arm, pypy

As per my client's request I need to distribute a closed source python program with just the *.pyc files, and must be run via pypy.

The program has a  subdirectory where various modules are imported:

```
start.pyc
backends/
   server.pyc
   ...
```

the first line of start.py imports backends.server, and it works when running in standard "python" mode.
But if I strip all the *.py files, and try to run

```
(pypy)home@user:~ python start.pyc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./start.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named backends.server
```

I get an error saying no module named 'backends' is found, even if the 'backends' subdir is there, and the server.pyc file is there.

I remember there was a switch for pypy for exactly this behavior, but I can't seem to find it anymore. Any help?

PS this is the pypy/python version we use on an embedded ARM system.

```
Python 2.7.10 (c95650101a99, Sep 06 2016, 11:02:19)
[PyPy 5.4.1 with GCC 4.7.2 20120731 (prerelease)]
```

Comment: The `.pyc` files contain CPython bytecode. PyPy has its own internal code representation, making (as far as I'm aware) `.pyc` files incompatible with PyPy. The same problem is asked on this mailing list: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2011-May/007395.html

Comment: This seems strange because from a PyPy venv I can launc 'python -m compileall . ' and regenerate all the *.pyc of my projects. Which I guess are generated by PyPy in a Pypy-compatible way. Moreover if I execute a pyc file with pypy it gives me the above error, which is meaningful and coherent with what should be in the pyc (i.e. an import )

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to enable loading lone .pyc files (mostly untested but should work).  You need to translate pypy from sources with:

```
cd pypy/goal
./rpython -Ojit targetpypystandalone.py --objspace-lonepycfiles
```

If obfuscation is the goal, then you can also write your own import hook and load the modules from your own custom file format (then it works in a standard PyPy).

Finally, I'm not sure but I think that .pyc files are still found and loaded from .zip files.  So if you package your application's .pyc files into a .zip and make the .zip available for the normal importing mechanism (I think it means adding the path to the .zip file itself into sys.path), then it should work in a standard PyPy too.

Usual comments about the ease of reverse-engineering .pyc files back to .py files apply.

Comment: Thanks, but translating with rpython does not work since I don't seem to have rpython on the machine. I remember doing it some months ago in a simpler way. And the command line switch --objspace-lonepycfiles is not recognized by pypy (either wit singe or double dash, it is treated as an unknown option). Maybe I'm invoking the wrong way?

Comment: It's not an option you can give to pypy at runtime.  If you don't want to investigate how to translate a custom pypy, try the .zip choice.

Comment: thanks but could you be more specific? Shoud I change something in the import instruction before packaging everything in a zip? Have you got a link besides https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html ? Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html#examples : it works on PyPy (as well as CPython) if the .zip file contains .pyc files instead of .py.